# How to protect the access to a local server with a certificate, Apache httpd, and ngrok?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, https, httpd

If we have the following scenario:

- a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS machine
- a third party server running on port `10000` of this machine and already configuring a self-signed `certificate` (https://localhost:10000)
- a ngrok `tcp` tunnel exposing port `10000` to the world (https://0.tcp.ngrok.io:1234/)

How can we configure an Apache httpd server in a way that only the clients with the same certificate will be able to access and see the contents of the ngrok public url (https://0.tcp.ngrok.io:1234/)?

*Some of the things I tried were*:

- Copying the certificate to `/etc/apache2/ssl`
- Enabling the ssl module with `a2enmod ssl`
- Configuring the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to have a section like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key.pem

  SSLVerifyClient require
  SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
  SSLCADNRequestFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
  SSLVerifyDepth 1

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request_log \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

- Restarting the apache server `service apache2 restart`

But unfortunately this is not working yet. Should I change the strategy to something different?

Comment: The scenario you first describe makes no mention of Apache, so AFAWK, you can change its settings all you want it won't change a thing. As a side note, do you really use ngrok in production?!

Comment: @Ginnungagap, yes, it could be another thing, I was thinking about nginx. I was considering httpd because the third party server recommend this tutorial here: https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html
It's not really a production thing, but a side project of mine, but because of some restrictions, I can only see the UI if externalize the server

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do client certificate authentication.  The tutorial you linked only shows the steps for the client to be able to verify the server's identity - not for the server to verify the client.  If that's the case, you need to (among other things) generate a CSR on the client machine, sign it using the server's self-signed CA, and install the result on the client.  For a side-project, there may be simpler and equally effective solutions (whitelisting your IP for port 1234 at the firewall comes to mind).

Comment: @BrandonXavier, as you said, I think this is a matter for client certification. It looks like we need to define the server and client certificates and require the ssl verification. I didn't try yet, but it looks like this is the way. And I think nginx is better suitable for this task